# Angular: Interpolation Arithmetic Doesn't Work for component properties

Tags: angular, components, interpolation, angular2-template

Why does this work:

```
<span>${{10 + 20}}</span>
<!-- <span>$30</span> -->
```

But this doesn't work:

```
<span>${{cart.subtotal + cart.taxTotal}}</span>
<!-- <span>$1020</span> -->
```

It seems that the properties from the component are passed to the template as strings, irregardless that they are typed as `numbers` on the component itself.

Comment: Can you throw together a quick plunkr? I ran your code with no issues.

Comment: Are you sure they're of the number type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `$` angular tries to parse it as a template expression.
How ever you can use the **[currency pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe)** to display the currency on your template

```
<span>{{cart.subtotal + cart.taxTotal | currency:'USD':true}}</span>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/VBlH6oaXQCEpoVxjPKrz?p=preview)**

Comment: Get an `InvalidPipeArgument: '1020' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'`. Even tried taking the $ out from in front of the brackets and that didn't work

Comment: what version you are using

Comment: _If you are using $ angular tries to parse it as a template expression_ - what do you mean by template expression with regards to `$`? Can point to specific documentation place where `$` is explained in regards to the template expression?